# can possible? to create a xibcell indexPath 0 on the top of (second cell) while second xib cell is in function viewForHeaderInSection in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWMET.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET8oO.jpg)

I created 3 xib tableview cell's 
basically I build design similar to instagram own profile showing design in this when we scroll the ***tableview***  its ***second cell(centre cell)***  on scrolling become a header while first cell scroll

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] your question.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can't use dequeue to create header view. and if you want to the cell to stick as a header then you can create a simple UIView with an xib (not a cell), and use it header.